# how can i change the foreground of wpf datagrid cell by his value that is binding by a array?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, styles, cell

I need to change only the textcolor of a cell content, but my cell is binding by a list of entities that content a array property (that i need).

this is my code:
**-- Entity:**

```
  public class MyEntity{
        public string Name { get; set; }     
        public IList<string> Values { get; set; }   
        }
```

**-- Datagrid and List**

```
ObservableCollection<MyEntity> list;
// ....
DataGrid.ItemsSource = list;
```

**-- Style**

```
<Style x:Key="DgCellStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
          <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Values[{Binding self}]}" Value="KK">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

-- If i use Binding="{Binding Values[2]}" it work, but the foregound is apply for the row (not the current cell).

Comment: Can you clarify your issue further pls, the second column in your datagrid is bound to a collection, based on what value in the collection you want the cell's foreground to be affected ?

Comment: You can't use binding for Values Array. Values[{Binding self}] is Incorrect. You should find another way to go.

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this by using IValueConverer

```
public class simpleListCheckConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null && ((List<String>)value).Contains((string)parameter))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And Xaml :

```
<local:simpleListCheckConverter x:Key="simpleListCheckConverter1"/>
    <Style x:Key="DgCellStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Values, Converter={StaticResource simpleListCheckConverter1 },ConverterParameter=kk}" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

And For Row color change :

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Values, Converter={StaticResource simpleListCheckConverter1 },ConverterParameter=kk}" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I need to check the value that is in specified index, i don't need to check if contains !!!. Ex.:  Binding="{Binding Values[row_index]}"